# Consider a random experiment with equiprobable sample space $\Omega = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$. Define the random variable $X(\omega)=2(\omega-3)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a random experiment with equiprobable sample space $\Omega = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$. Define the random variable $X(\omega)=2(\omega-3)$. What are the possible values of $X$? Calculate $P(X=0), P(X\in \{2, 3\}), P(X\geq 0), P(X<0), P(X^2=1)$ and $P(2X-4=0)$.

Then,

$$ X(1)=2(1-3)=-4; X(2)=2(2-3)=-2; X(3)=2(3-3)=0; X(4)=2(4-3)=2 $$

$$ X(5)=2(5-3)=4; X(6)=2(6-3)=6 $$

are the possible values of $X$. Is this correct?

**$(X\in A)=\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega)\in A\}$**

$(X\in \{2, 3\})=\{4, 5, 6\}$, then $P(X\in \{2, 3\})=4+5+6$ Is this correct?

How would you calculate the probabilities? Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I agree with your possible values of $X$, but not your calculation of $P(X \in \{2,3\})$. 
 $P(X \in \{2,3\})$ is a probability, so it has a value in $[0,1]$ and therefore can't be $15$.  I'm not sure how you related that to the set $\{4,5,6\}$, either: $X(5) = 4 \not \in \{2,3\}$, so $5 \not \in \{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \in \{2,3\}\}$.

Comment: @user6247850 Could you show how to calculate this probability? I am confused.

Comment: "Consider a random experiment with **equiprobable** sample space..."  There are six outcomes in the sample space, and the *total* probability must equal one, so...

Comment: $\mathsf P(X=x)=\mathsf P(\omega=\tfrac 12x+3)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp How do you get $\omega = (1/2)x+3$? That part is not clear to me.

Comment: $X=2(\omega-3)$, so $\omega = (1/2)x+3$ exactly when $X=x$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry for not being so observant, how does that help me calculate the probability I'm looking for?

Comment: You know the probability for each outcome.  Determine which outcomes correspond to the event.  EG: $X\in\{2,3\}$ corresponds to $\omega\in\{4,4\tfrac 12\}$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp $P(X=0)=1/6, P(X\in {2, 3})=1/6+0, P(X\geq 0)=P(X=0)+P(X=2)+P(X=4)+P(X=6)=4/6, P(X<0)=P(X=-2)+P(X=-4)=2/6$

Comment: Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Your calculation are not correct:
1. $\{X\in\{2,3\}\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:2(\omega-3)\in\{2,3\}\}=\{4\}$.
Notice that all values of $X$ are even numbers so no $\omega\in\Omega$ is sent to $3$ by $X$. Now $2(\omega-3)=2$ happens if $\omega=4$, and $4\in\Omega$.
2. $\{X=0\}=\{\omega\in\Omega: 2(\omega-3)=0\}=\{3\}$
3. $\{X\geq0\}=\{\omega\in\Omega: 2(\omega-3)\geq0\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:\omega\geq3\}=\{3,4,5,6\}$
4. $\{X<0\}=\Omega\setminus\{X\geq0\}=\{1,2\}$
5. $\{X^2=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:4(\omega-3)^2=1\}=\emptyset$.
6. $\{2X-4=0\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:4(\omega-3)-4=0\}=\{4\}$

Comment: Also, a probability is a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz I tried that, some results match. But now to calculate the probability I am confused

Comment: @Gabriela: match what?  In your OP you mentioned that each element in $\Omega$ has the same probability, i.e., $P(\{\omega\})=\frac16$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$. Then all you have to do in each of the question you have is to count the number of elements on each event and divide by $6$. for example, $P\{X\geq0\}=\frac46$, $P(X^2=1)=0$, $P(X\in\{2,3\})=\tfrac14$, etc. If you edit you question with what exactly is makinf this confusing, I will try to help out.

Comment: Why $P(X\in \{2, 3 \})=1/4$? Shouldn't it be $1/6$?

Comment: @Gabriela: yes, it should be $1/6$.